# Regex in register route not working for parameters

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am working with a custom WordPress REST API endpoint and I want to be able to accept `string` and `int` values for the `round` parameter. This is because the round could be `1` (i.e. Round 1) or `semi-final`, `final` and so on.

I have added these Regex declarations into the parameter code but so far that is still returning a `404` at the endpoint (standard behaviour if the endpoint fails)

```
register_rest_route('wp/v2/statistics', 'rounds/(?P<season>\d+)/(?P<round>[a-zA-Z0-9-]\d+)', [
    'methods'  => 'GET, POST',
    'callback' => 'serveRoundsRoute',
]);
```

Can anyone help me out? Some example requests are below:

- Round 10: /statistics/rounds/2019/10
- Semi-Final: /statistics/round/2019/semi-finals

Furthermore with that `regex` in place the `int` round submissions also fail but work with the simple `(?P<round>\d+)` parameter.

Comment: Replace `(?P<season>\d+)/(?P<round>[a-zA-Z0-9-]\d+)` with `(?P<season>[^/]+)/(?P<round>[^/]+)`

Comment: You sir, are the gift of today. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The `\d+` pattern matches 1+ digits and `[a-zA-Z0-9-]\d+` matches a letter, digit or hyphen followed with 1+ digits. You might remove `\d` from the second regex and use `[a-zA-Z0-9-]+` to match any 1+ alphanumeric/hyphen chars, but it seems you may use a more generic approach and match any chars but `/`.

Replace

```
(?P<season>\d+)/(?P<round>[a-zA-Z0-9-]\d+)
```

with

```
(?P<season>[^/]+)/(?P<round>[^/]+)
```

The `[^/]+` pattern matches 1 or more chars other than forward slash.

Answer (score 0):

In order to improve the answers from this questions, as the previous users mentioned [^/]+ works just fine BUT in case you are also using "&" for other options you could also do [^/&]+ in order to avoid mixing them.

[^/]+  <--- takes in count only the "/"

[^/&]+  <--- takes in count "/" and "&"